# Unix: Slash after directory names or not

Tags: unix

What is the difference between the following commands?

```
mv foo bar
mv foo/ bar/
mv foo/ bar
mv foo bar/
```

Or is there no difference? Or does it depend on the command being used? Think for example I read that the rsync behavior changes a bit depending on which version you use. Does anyone have a good explanation so I don't have to guess anymore and feel like I know what I'm doing?

Comment: It's true for rsync. It starts the copying either with the directory itself or with the items under it, depending on whether you skip or add the trailing slash, respectively.

Comment: @maxelost: Could you add an answer with some examples so it is crystal clear which does what?

Comment: Mikel answered it quite clearly below, I think.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Many Unix utilities treat symlinks differently depending on whether there is a trailing slash.

This behavior is described in the [POSIX Symbolic Link documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_59) and is also mentioned in the [GNU coreutils documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Trailing-slashes.html).

Basically, the trailing slash means to follow (or "dereference") the symlink.

For example, in the code below, `dirlink` means the symlink, but `dirlink/` means the directory the symlink points to.  `rm` won't remove a directory unless you say `rm -r`, but `rm` without options will happily remove a symlink.

```
$ mkdir dir
$ ln -s dir dirlink
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 mikel mikel 4096 2011-02-02 22:26 dir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mikel mikel    3 2011-02-02 22:26 dirlink -> dir
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 mikel mikel 4096 2011-02-02 22:26 dir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mikel mikel    3 2011-02-02 22:26 dirlink -> dir
$ rm dirlink/
rm: cannot remove `dirlink/': Is a directory
$ rm dirlink
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 mikel mikel 4096 2011-02-02 22:26 dir
```

It's also useful for viewing the permissions of a directory, without having to bother whether the directory is a real directory or just a symlink to a directory.

```
$ ls -ld dirlink
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mikel mikel 3 2011-02-02 22:46 dirlink -> dir
$ ls -ld dirlink/
drwxr-xr-x 2 mikel mikel 4096 2011-02-02 22:46 dirlink/
```

and it still works for regular directories:

```
$ ls -ld dir
drwxr-xr-x 2 mikel mikel 4096 2011-02-02 22:46 dir
$ ls -ld dir/
drwxr-xr-x 2 mikel mikel 4096 2011-02-02 22:46 dir/
```

Another example is the `find` command.  If the `path` you ask it to search in is a symlink, it won't follow the symlink by default, meaning it only processes the symlink.  Adding a trailing slash makes it treat the symlink as the directory that the link points to.

```
$ find dir
dir
dir/file
$ find dirlink
dirlink
$ find dirlink/
dirlink/
dirlink/file
```

(some versions of find have a `-follow` or `-L` option, but that makes it follow all symlinks, not just the first one)

---

In the case of `rsync`, whether you should append a slash depends on whether you want the directory you're copying to be a subdirectory or not.

```
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/file
$ rsync -r dir dir.bak
$ find .
.
./dir
./dir/file
./dir.bak
./dir.bak/dir
./dir.bak/dir/file
$ rm -r dir.bak
$ rsync -r dir/ dir.bak
$ find .
.
./dir
./dir/file
./dir.bak
./dir.bak/file
```

In other words:

- `rsync dir dir.bak` copies `dir` into `dir.bak`, making `dir` inside `dir.bak`
- `rsync dir/ dir.bak` copies all the contents of `dir`, without making `dir` inside `dir.bak`

Answer (score 2):

As jsalonen already said, these commands indeed have identical results if `foo` and `bar` are, as a matter of fact, directories.

However, if `foo` and `bar` are not directories, then the command will fail if you append a trailing slash, and will succeed if you don't. Thing is, if the command succeeds, it'll probably not have the result you intended. In fact, you could even lose data if `foo` and `bar` are files (`bar` would be overwritten).

If your intention is to specify directories and not files, then you *should* use a trailing slash, because it makes the command more robust: if the expectation that `foo` or `bar` are directories fails, then the command will fail gracefully, instead of having unexpected results.

Also, some (rare) commands behave differently depending of the presence of a trailing slash, even with directories (one example is `rsync`).

Comment: Yeah, as I implied commands may or may not handle well trailing slashes. Its very good that you provided rsync as an example!